# Remove points outside defined 3D box inside PCL visualizer

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

In a given point cloud, I want to remove all the points which are less than `min` and greater than `max` for all `x`, `y` and `z` direction. Below is the sample code:

```
#include <pcl/io/io.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

// Define min and max for X, Y and Z
float minX = -0.1, minY = -0.5, minZ = -2.5;
float maxX = +0.1, maxY = +0.5, maxZ = +2.5;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr body (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("body.pcd", *body);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr bodyFiltered (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);

    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> filter;
    filter.setInputCloud (body);
    filter.setFilterFieldName ("x");
    filter.setFilterLimits (minX, maxX);
    filter.setFilterFieldName ("y");
    filter.setFilterLimits (minY, maxY);
    filter.setFilterFieldName ("z");
    filter.setFilterLimits (minZ, maxZ);
    filter.filter (*bodyFiltered);

    viewer.addPointCloud (bodyFiltered,"body");
    viewer.spin();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that only last filter is being applied. Any solution, please?

Comment: Can you show some sample data, sample output and explain how you conclude that only the last filter is applied?

Comment: @Yunnosch: The data was acquired from a sensor and it is very noisy. Presently, I am trying to find out the best bounds, so that I can remove most of the noise. By the way, is the above way looking correct to you?

Comment: In case you do not want to remove the points from the cloud but want to get the indices of valid points you can use `pcl::Clipper3D<PointT>::clipPointCloud3D`.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers: That seems a good alternative. However, my final objective is to remove the noise, which is present in the point cloud. I finally would like to have point cloud, which contains data bounded by the defined box.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What about using `pcl::CropBox`? ([documentation](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html))

```
pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> boxFilter;
boxFilter.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f(minX, minY, minZ, 1.0));
boxFilter.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f(maxX, maxY, maxZ, 1.0));
boxFilter.setInputCloud(body);
boxFilter.filter(*bodyFiltered);
```

To know why this filter takes Vector4f (and not Vector3f) see the comments below and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60976341/why-are-the-min-and-max-vectors-for-pclcropbox-4-dimensional).

Comment: Excellent. it works like charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gabriel Devillers, what is the use of **1.0** in `setMin` as well as in `setMax`? (documentation link you have mentioned is broken, probably because of PCL website update)

Comment: @Milan link fixed. This is because PCL often uses [homogeneous coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3847743) with 4 coordinates to work in 3D. I hard-coded w=1 which is the correct value to concatenate to coordinates x,y,z (from the question) in order to represent the 3D point x,y,z using homogeneous coordinates. That said, if you have a Vector4 which represents a point in space (w != 0) you can pass it without normalizing it yourself (i.e. getting w=1). I have no idea if passing a "point at infinity" (w = 0) would make sense for cropping.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers, thanks a lot for updating the link and for addressing my question. The link you shared on Homogeneous coordinates is also helpful. Thank you for that as well. Just to confirm, by "... if you have a Vector4 which represents a point in space (w != 0) you can pass it without normalizing it yourself" you meant: if I have a point represented by [4, 8, 6, 2] in a Homogeneous coordinate system which corresponds to a point [2, 4, 3, 1] in Ecludian coordinate system, I can directly pass [4, 8, 6, 2], right?

Comment: @Milan that is what I meant, but I just checked the source code and it does not seem to use the fourth coordinate, so it seems to only accept normalized homogeneous coordinates. Feel free to make tests to confirm or refute this hypothesis.

Comment: Hi @GabrielDevillers in my application, `setMin` & `setMax` are not enough as the region I want to crop is somewhat tilted. So, just to confirm through `setRotation` & `setTranslate` I can rotate & translate, respectively, that parallelogram cropBox w.r.t. the coordinate system of the point cloud, not the coordinate system of cropBox itself, right? How can I rotate that parallelogram cropBox w.r.t. its own axis? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4):

You have found what the [documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_pass_through.html#details) makes clear.

> PassThrough passes points in a cloud based on constraints for one
>   particular field of the point type.

For multiple fields a different filter should be used, such as [ConditionalRemoval](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_conditional_removal.html)

The following is untested, but it'll be something like this.

```
pcl::ConditionOr<PointT>::Ptr range_cond (new pcl::ConditionOr<PointT> ()); 
range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::Ptr (new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("x", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, minX)));
range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::Ptr (new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("x", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, maxX)));
range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::Ptr (new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("y", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, minY)));
range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::Ptr (new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("y", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, maxY)));
range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::Ptr (new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("z", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, minZ)));
range_cond->addComparison (pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>::Ptr (new pcl::FieldComparison<PointT>("z", pcl::ComparisonOps::LT, maxZ)));

pcl::ConditionalRemoval<PointT> range_filt;
range_filt.setInputCloud(body);
range_filt.setCondition (range_cond);
range_filt.filter(*bodyFiltered);
```

Comment: I am checking it... I included the headers `#include <pcl/filters/conditional_removal.h>` and `#include <pcl/impl/point_types.hpp>` but still getting many errors such as `error: ‘PointT’ was not declared in this scope`, `error: ‘range_cond’ was not declared in this scope` etc.

Comment: `using PointT = pcl::PointXYZRGBA;`

Comment: I just realised that your code has removed the point cloud inside the defined bounds. Why!!!! I want to remove the points outside the box and keep the points inside the box. Can you please have a look again into it?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Think about it. If you understood my answer you would have known how easy it was to fix my wrong-way-round logic. I've amended the answer. Anyway you changed your accepted answer so presumably copy+paste works for you.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I think it is much more flexible and can be applied in various kind of comparison. As you said, I also found out the logic to change the output. Indeed, it was interesting to know this solution.  Anyway, the other solution was short and exact as per the requirement and can't be ignored without accepting it. Hope you understand it.