# Why are the min and max vectors for pcl::CropBox 4-dimensional?

Tags: point-cloud-library

The `setMin` and `setMax` methods of the [`pcl::CropBox`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html) filter each take an `Eigen::Vector4f` as a parameter.

Why 4f and not 3f? What's the fourth dimension for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What's the Vector4F for?**

The Vector4f corresponds to the [homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). For example, (3, 4, 5, 1) and (6, 8, 10, 2) is the same point in homogeneous coordinates system. You can normalize(a, b, c, d) to (a/d, b/d, c/d, 1) in this case.

> Easy answer is: **Just set the last digit to 1**

**Why PCL CropBox needs Vector4f?**

It's because PCL CropBox can handle any box transformation via [setTransform](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_box.html#a93f464be457c0402aa7a53b9face4a4b)

Transformation matrix usually contains a 4x4 matrix, example shown below where `r` is a 3x3 rotation matrix and `t` is a 3-d vector

```
[[r0, r1, r2, t0],
 [r3, r4, r5, t1],
 [r6, r7, r8, t2],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  1]]
```

It's just easier to matrix multiply a homogeneous coordinate (1x4) vector with (4x4) matrix.

Feel free to ask more question, as I can update this answer.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! I guess it would be more convenient for the user if there was an overload where the method just converted a Vector3f to homogeneous coordinates internally, but this clarifies it!

Comment: I just checked CropBox's source code and it does not seem to use the fourth coordinates, so it seems that it assumes normalized coordinates (i.e. fourth element equal to 1).

Comment: As PCL has updated the website, I think the link for **`setTransform`** needs to be updated. The updated on is this: https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_crop_box_3_01pcl_1_1_p_c_l_point_cloud2_01_4.html#a32a787e9470224662c400c3a10d877de  right?

Comment: I have other queries as well: (1) I have been trying to understand how `setTransform` work but so far haven't got a solid understanding. So, to confirm, when I specify `setMin`, `setMax`, by default, my `cropBox` would be **parallelogram**, right? (2) Through `setRotation` & `setTranslate` I can rotate & translate, respectively, that parallelogram w.r.t. the coordinate system of the point cloud not the coordinate system of cropBox itself, right? But even in this case my parallelogram would remain parallelogram only, right?

Comment: (3) Through `setTransform` can I transform my parallelogram cropBox to **parallelepiped** cropBox? If yes then how? (4) If yes then I have another doubt: as per the link I mentioned above, " `setTransform` sets a transformation that should be applied to the cloud before filtering." So, it transforms the point cloud not the cropBox, right?

Comment: If possible, could you & @GabrielDevillers please take a look at my detailed question about these confusions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63569343/10358768